# QGraphicsView dragMoveEvent, mouseMoveEvent, mousePressEvent used in the same time

Tags: qt, drag, mousemove, qgraphicsview

In QGraphicsView,

`setDragMode(QGraphicsView::ScrollHandDrag);`

This line of code did what I want: scroll contents while dragging. However, if I have implemented `mouseMoveEvent` or `mousePressEvent` for my custom needs, the `setDragMode(QGraphicsView::ScrollHandDrag)` magic disappears.

These built-in functions seem have some dependencies, most times they're convenient, but when you implement one of them, you break up the chain between that dependencies so that some of them gone.

I don't want to implement all these function from ground up. How to solve this dilemma?

==================Edit 12/13================

Ok, I'm trying but...

```
void MyView::mouseMoveEvent( QMouseEvent* event )
{

    // Notice: event->button() always return Qt::NoButton for "mouse move events"
    // so event->button() == Qt::LeftButton won't work in this case
    if(event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        this->dragMoveEvent(dynamic_cast<QDragMoveEvent*>(event));
    }
    else
    {
        ...
    }


}
```

These code fails because `QMouseEvent*` cannot be cast into `QDragMoveEvent*`, any idea?

Comment: Have you tried calling `QGraphicsView::mouseMoveEvent()` and `QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent()` inside your `mouseMoveEvent()` and `mousePressEvent()` functions?

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. But, how do I call QGraphicsView::dragMoveEvent() inside MyView::mouseMoveEvent()?

Comment: Why would you call `QGraphicsView::dragMoveEvent` inside `MyView::mouseMoveEvent()`?

Comment: I need when mouse moving 1). without left button pressed: detect hover event so that I can fetch the pixel value of the mouse position, 2). with left button pressed: treat it as a drag event to act as setDragMode(QGraphicsView::ScrollHandDrag)

Comment: If you set drag mode to `QGraphicsView::ScrollHandDrag`, the hover events shouldn't be activated during the drag. As long as you call `QGraphicsView::mouseMoveEvent` from your own `mouseMoveEvent` function, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

@thuga is right.  At the end of your subclassed functions put a reference to the original function.  Like so:

```
void MyGraphicsView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * e)
{
    static QPoint oldPos;
        if(!m_not_dragging)
        {
                // some logic for drawing something based on the mouse move
            // Edit added this function call.
            doMyDrag(e->pos(), oldPos);
            oldPos = e->pos();
        }
        else
        {
                QGraphicsView::mouseMoveEvent(e);
        }
}
// EDIT added the two functions below
void MyGraphicsView::dragMoveEvent(QMouseEvent * e)
{
    static QPoint oldPos;
    doMyDrag(e->pos(), oldPos);
    oldPos = e->pos();

    QGraphicsView::dragMoveEvent(e);
}

void MyGraphicsView::doMyDrag(QPoint new, QPoint old)
{
    // common drawing logic for both official drag events 
    //and pseudo drag events.
}
```

You could even determine `m_not_dragging` based on `e->button()` right in this function call, but this is a quick example of one way that you could have both your custom method and the default method still available.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. But, how do I call QGraphicsView::dragMoveEvent() inside MyView::mouseMoveEvent()?

Comment: If a drag didn't really start, you probably should just have the core functionality of the two functions in a third function.